# Strange behavior : set vector profiler

Tags: c++, sfml

i have a strange profiler cpu usage on the code below : i set different variable in a vector the same way but they have a completely different CPU Usage.

```
sf::VertexArray vertices;

for (int y = 0; y < map->mapSize.y; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < map->mapSize.x; ++x) {
        int index = y * map->mapSize.x + x;

        vertices[index * 4].position = sf::Vector2f(x, y); //5% CPU Usage
        vertices[index * 4 + 1].position = sf::Vector2f(x, y);//30% CPU Usage
        vertices[index * 4 + 2].position = sf::Vector2f(x, y);//15% CPU Usage
        vertices[index * 4 + 3].position = sf::Vector2f(x, y);//36% CPU Usage
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: How do you profile these parts? Is the "CPU usage" only for your thread, and not the total or all running processes and threads during that time?

Comment: I profile with visual studio 2015 by using the cpu usage tools and this was almost the only code in the program for now, and by profiling multiple time this was always the same CPU usage stats approximately.

Comment: Why do you care that much about CPU usage?

Comment: Because just this part of code are going to run a lot of time each frame so if i can optimize it this would be great, and by the meantime i want to know more about the reason of this cpu usage difference.

Comment: are you benchmarking your whole program or just this small bit of code?  If you're just benchmarking this code, the optimizer is probably chunking out huge chunks of the work in certain circumstances.  It's a long movie, but it's immensely informative on benchmarking and entertaining as well -- though it doesn't talk about using MSVC -- it's all UNIXy, but the ideas are the same.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXaxk27zwlk

Comment: Also, your profiler is probably doing statistical sampling (addressed in the movie linked above), so the numbers don't necessarily correspond to the actual time spent in the functions.  The only way to really tell what is going on is to look at the assembly generated by the optimizing compiler.